# Asp.Net Core: Add data to IdentityDbContext or use DbContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I work with **Asp.Net Core WebApi** project.

Can I add my tables to *IdentityDbContext*, like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<ProgrammerRole> ProgrammerRoles { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubProject> SubProjects { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    }
```

Or do I need to create a second DbContext. And if i create a second DbContext 
how can I communicate wiht User in *IdentityDbContext*.

And my second question:
If i add data in *IdentityDbContext*, like above, How do I get the data from my tables in *ApplicationDbContext*?
Because i need to pass **DbContextOptions** object every time I create a new instance оf *ApplicationDbContext*. I do this in **Startup.cs**:

```
// ===== Add DbContext ========
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I saw in older version of Asp.Net Core, that i can pass Connection String in IdentityDbContext constructor, but now only DbContextOptions. 
And i can't do, for example this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Project> GetRoles()
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                return db.Projects;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Can I add my tables to IdentityDbContext, like this:

Yes, it is how you create custom tables. You do not need to create another `DbContext`. E.g.

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Project>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

**Note:** you might need to run `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` and `dotnet ef database update` for database migration.

> using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext()) {...}

You *should not create or manage* `ApplicationDbContext` inside controller. If you do so, they become tightly coupled, and you cannot implement unit tests.

Instead, you let dependency inversion (DI) container manage it for you. E.g.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UserController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Project> GetRoles()
    {
        return _context.Projects;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem, i just replaced code in my ApplicationDbContext, and get connection string from method:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(GetConnectionString());
        }

        private static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            const string databaseName = "EmployeeReportsDb";
            const string databasePass = "SuperPuper_Random_DB-key!";

            return $"Server=localhost;" +
                   $"database={databaseName};" +
                   $"Trusted_Connection = True;" +
                   $"MultipleActiveResultSets = True;" +
                   $"pwd={databasePass};" +
                   $"pooling=true;";
        }

        public DbSet<ProgrammerRole> ProgrammerRoles { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubProject> SubProjects { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    }
```

here is the resource: https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8